# How to give EJB reference when instantiated?

Tags: java, ejb, inject

i still struggling learning java injection

- i have EJB class, it name is **MyEJB**
- i have another class, my application begin in this class, it name is **Main**
- Class **Main** call  **MyEJB**, then i need class **MyEJB** to have a
  reference to Class **Main**

**MyEJB**

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class MyEJB{

   private Main main;

   public MyEJB(){

   }

   public void doSomething(){
       //later i will do something here with class Main
       if(main == null){
           System.out.println("main is null");
       }else{
           System.out.println("main not null token = "+main.token);
       }
   }


}
```

**Main**

```
@EJB
MyEJB myEJB;
private String token = "123";

// i will call this function
public void test(){
  myEJB.doSomething();
}
```

i need **MyEJB** to have class **Main** reference when it instantiated

How to do this?

forgive my english

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way how to pass parameters to the constructor of the injected EJB because initialization of this object is performed by container and you can't do it manually. So only viable solution is to introduce a setter in `MyEJB` and than just call `myEJB.setMain(this);`